# How to change the input atrribute of JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing

I've used a JButton,when the button is clicked,running these codes:

```
StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) textPane.getDocument(); 
MutableAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet(); 
int p0=textPane.getSelectionStart();
int p1=textPane.getSelectionEnd();
if(p0!=p1){
   StyleConstants.setForeground(attr, Color.RED); 
   doc.setCharacterAttributes(p0,p1-p0, attr,false);
}
textPane.getInputAttributes().addAttributes(attr);
```

The characters from p0 to p1 did change to red

But the characters I typed in is still black,not red:(

Examples:

I typed "12345" and select "234".

The new 5's still black.

[image]

But if I type "1234" and select "234".

The new 5's will be red.

Even without  "textPane.getInputAttributes().addAttributes(attr);"

[image]

Comment: i guess you have to add the StyleDocument to the textpane again with set...

Comment: @KevinEsche setting the document is useless since it is already set on the JTextPane. @ user1850337: post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that illustrates your problem. AFAICT, if the new characters you type are not within p0/p1 (included), it is only normal to have them in black and not red.

Comment: So the getInputAttributes() method can't work?

Comment: i tried it out, and it is working, what you wrote

Comment: u can try to not select the last characters of JTextPane. it will always be red even without changing InputAttributes().I dont know the reason :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that getInputAttribute reflects the characters attribute of the current caret location.

1. You select "234" (caret is after 4)--> InputAttributes reflect the ones of "234"
2. You apply a red style foreground on "234" and on the current InputAttributes (which are supposed to be the same)
3. You move the caret after "5"-->InputAttributes are updated and reflect the ones of "5"

Now, here is some code to get yourself inspired from (this is not really operational) and you probably have to listen for caret moves (hard to tell without knowing what you are trying to achieve):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class TestTextPane {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTextPane.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTextPane textPane2 = new JTextPane();
        textPane2.setText("12345");
        frame.add(textPane2);
        JButton button = new JButton("Make it red");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                StyleConstants.setForeground(set, Color.RED);
                int p0 = textPane2.getSelectionStart();
                int p1 = textPane2.getSelectionEnd();
                if (p0 != p1) {
                    StyledDocument doc = textPane2.getStyledDocument();
                    doc.setCharacterAttributes(p0, p1 - p0, set, false);
                }
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textPane2.getCaret().setDot(textPane2.getText().length());
                        MutableAttributeSet inputAttributes = textPane2.getInputAttributes();
                        inputAttributes.addAttributes(set);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        button.setFocusable(false);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestTextPane t = new TestTextPane();
                t.initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```